# reduce laptop touch pad sensitivity in ubuntu

Tags: laptop, touchpad, ubuntu-10.10

I have Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick Meerkat installed. The problem is that the tap to click feature on my touchpad is too sensitive in ubuntu. It works fine with windows. I randomly end up clicking things while moving the mouse. Its very irritating. Any solutions ? I have a HP Probook 4410s laptop.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to turn it off? I assume the trackpad has real buttons nearby.

Comment: i mean i could probably get used to it being off. But i would prefer a fix rather than avoiding the problem.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**This works for me in Ubuntu 10.10**

To see what trackpad you've got and what it's called, try:

```
xinput list
```

My device is called "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"

There are 3 finger pressure settings: low, high & press. See what their current values are with something like:

```
xinput list-props "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" |grep -i finger
```

Change the values with something like:

```
xinput set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Finger" 50 90 255
```

By increasing the second parameter, you require more finger pressure for the trackpad to respond. The first parameter controls release pressure, the third is to detect a button press (I think).

Comment: I needed to put commas in between the numerical values, as running it without commas resulted in a non-functioning trackpad. Also, my values were 12, 35, 255, in case someone tries it and 50, 90, 255 makes clicking not work at all. I have an ALPS GlidePoint.

Comment: This also worked for me on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: workis in Ubuntu 13.04 too.

Comment: Works on 13.10 too, 10, 50, 0 seems to be a good setting on macbook 4.1

Comment: on my macbook pro unibody the commannd was:
$ sudo xinput set-prop "bcm5974" "Synaptics Finger" 10, 50, 0

Comment: This works, but on restart, it goes back to old values. How do I fix the values so that it sticks?

Comment: This works even on the unstable release of 14.04. :-) Thanks!

Comment: I have an HP Pavilion with a SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad running XUbuntu 15.10. I put this in .profile so it runs each time the laptop boots:

xinput set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Finger" 12, 35, 255

Comment: Surprisingly, my device vanished after I executed the commands. Before I had two devices Synaptics, and Dell. Now only the Dell touchpad. Should I put up a separate question?

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04 you need the spaces and the commas - you can see by matching the output from the `list-props` command which for me came out as `Synaptics Finger (297): 25, 30, 0`. If you try submitting `12,35,255` I got a `BadMatch` error, if you submit `12 35 255` nothing changes.

Answer (score 7):

This may be silly but do you have `gpointing-device-settings` installed?

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep gpointing
```

Should show it if you do have it installed. If not try installing it with `apt-get` or `aptitude`.

Comment: i do have it installed. No options from there really helped.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 20, use these instructions based on the [Adjust Touchpad Sensitivity](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad#Adjust_Touchpad_Sensitivity) section of the SynapticsTouchpad help page.

First, determine the device number, `id`, of your touchpad device.

```
xinput list
```

(Optional but helpful) In a terminal, you can monitor events emitted by that device:

```
xinput --test <id>
```

NOTE: While the test is running, you may be unable to select ranges of text in your terminal.

(Optional but helpful) In another terminal, you can monitor for changes in the device properties:

```
xinput --watch-props <id>
```

The sensitivity of the touchpad is controlled by the `Synaptics Finger` properties, three numbers described in the [synaptics manpage](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man4/synaptics.4.html):

```
Option "FingerLow" "integer"
       When  finger  pressure  drops  below this value, the driver counts it as a release.
       Property: "Synaptics Finger"

Option "FingerHigh" "integer"
       When finger pressure goes above this value,  the  driver  counts  it  as  a  touch.
       Property: "Synaptics Finger"

Option "FingerPress" "integer"
       When  finger  pressure  goes  above  this  value,  the driver counts it as a press.
       Currently a press is equivalent to putting the  touchpad  in  trackstick  emulation
       mode. Property: "Synaptics Finger"
```

Use `xinput --set-prop` to set these values:

```
xinput --set-prop <id> "Synaptics Finger" 50, 80, 255
```

You may have to play with the values to find your preferred thresholds. When you change them, you should see the change reflected in the `--watch-props` terminal.